# Image disappear when CARD Component is added -React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to add an **image** and **card** component (from `react-native-elements` library) in my screen (image at the top & card element in the bottom).

But in my final output, Only the card element is shown but the image is not shown in my screen. Anyone can help? Much appreciate!

### My Code :

```
 <View style={styles.FirstContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Card>
        <View style={styles.container}>
                <Icon type='font-awesome-5' name="angle-left" size={80} />
                <Text style={{paddingBottom:20}}>
                {'\n'}
                    Hello world 
                    {'\n'}
                    {'\n'}
                    
                    hello world
                </Text>               
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container}>
                <Icon type='font-awesome-5' name="angle-left" size={80} />
                <Text style={{paddingBottom:20}}>
                {'\n'}
                    Hello world 
                    {'\n'}
                    {'\n'}
                    
                    hello world
                </Text>             
        </View>

        <View style={styles.container}>
                <Icon type='font-awesome-5' name="angle-left" size={80} />
                <Text style={{paddingBottom:20}}>
                {'\n'}
                    Hello world 
                    {'\n'}
                    {'\n'}
                    
                    hello world
                </Text>                    
        </View> 
        </Card>

    </View>
```

### My styleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
FirstContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    flexDirection: "column"
},

img: {
    flex: 0.5,
    maxWidth: '100%',
},
title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingRight: 50
},
container: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignItems: "center",
},
})
```

My output:
[image]